# JQuery widget And Chrome inspector

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome inspector is very powerfull in debugging. I often use the console to search for a specific function. For example, when I have a recompute() javascript function, I want to add a breakpoint in the function :

- I type recompute in the console
- Chrome shows the function stub
- I click on it and it sends me directly to the source tab in the correct VM containing the function
- I add the breakpoint and Voilà :)

I am now working with Jquery widgets like this :

```
$.widget( "app.Recomputer", {


    recompute: function () {
        // Code where I want to break
    }
};
```

Is there a way to make Chrome Inspector to open the Source tab where this code is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open your HTML page or site and go to debugger window ( Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>  **OR**  <kbd>F12</kbd> )

Then Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Type the function name in the search text box and search, Then you can see the function name in the result and click on it.

You can add a breakpoint on the function and continue the debugging

***Note:-*** Some times you can not get anything on the search result when use script in MVC partial view and like this. So please place the script file in your head tag section or bundling. That means the script file must be load in the initial load of the webpages, and this is also a good practice.